# Importing to Notepad

Tags: vbscript, notepad

I have a problem with exporting texts to notepad.
I used `adwriteline` to denote each files but when a file has text with new line or like this "¶", the code went wrong. The problem is that at my computer, this new line is imported INVISIBLY to notepad (not to mention that this exported invisible new line is successfully imported) but when I tried it on other PC, the new line is VISIBLE. Thus, producing an error.

Thanks and regards.

EDIT:

The error occurs when the exported text has new line in its sentence

EXPORT:

```
adoStreamExport.WriteText Filepath &"' '" & child.Height & "' '" & child.Width, adWriteLine
```

IMPORT:

```
fileIn = Split(Replace(adoStreamImport.ReadText, vbCrLf, "' '"), "' '")

scanText fileIn(indexCount), fileIn(indexCount + 2), fileIn(indexCount + 3)

Case "Text" SetValue value, value2, value3
```

Comment: Please clarify what went wrong. Example of output/error and what is desired instead.

Comment: It sounds like you might be having a problem with the Byte Order Mark. If you show your code, especially the type of encoding you're using, this would reveal the problem.

Comment: Are you sure this is VB.NET? It looks a lot more like old VB or maybe even VBScript.

Comment: Please provide more context. The code you posted does not look like valid VBScript. A demonstration of the issue would be helpful, too.